# What is a better word than "trouble" in "The trouble of something"?

Tags: word-request

I receive a lot of non-junk emails each day, and most of them are not important and they are sent to everyone in my workplace, and the important ones are buried and hard to find.

Can this problem be called "The trouble of too many emails"?

I remember that I have seen some books that are titled with something similar to "The trouble of ...", but instead of "trouble", they use some better and more sophisticated or neutral words which I can't remember now. Do you happen to know some better word than "trouble"?

Thanks.

Comment: You yourself wrote *Can this **problem** be called "The trouble of too many emails"?* So I don't see why you're not happy to refer to *the **problem** of too many emails.* FWIW, if I were forced to use the word ***trouble*** in such contexts, I'd much prefer to refer to *the trouble **with** [receiving] too many emails [is blah blah]*.

Answer (score 1):

Some synonyms of "trouble" are

> problem
>   inconvenience
>   difficulty
>   distress
>   bother

any of those could be used in place of "trouble" in your sentence, but it depends on what you are trying to say since they could have slightly different nuanced meanings depending on how you are intending to use them.